# __pycache__ folder executes each time i run any other file in the folder

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, memcached, miniconda

I am learning python and I have a tutorial folder with 5 or 6 python files. One of them contained regex functions say `file_regex.py`. The problem is when I execute any other file in the folder, always `file_regex.py` is executed thus giving the output of `file_regex.py`. I am not importing file_regex.py in any of the other files.

`file_regex.py`

```
import re

sentence = ''' Jessica_is_27 year7s old, whereas John is 12 but Stephanie is 12 and Marco is 50 years '''

ages = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}', sentence)

names = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+', sentence) test = re.findall('\W', sentence)

print(ages) 

print(names) 

print(test)
```

This is because of the `__pycache__` folder created which has a `.pyc` file for `file_regex.py` file.

`regex.cpython-23.pyc`

```
� Vo�U�@sjddlZdZejde�Zejde�Zejde�Zee�ee�ee�dS)�NzX Jessica_is_27 year7s old, whereas John is 12 but Stephanie is 12 and Marco is 50 years z\d{1,3}z[A-Z][a-z]+z\W)�re�sentence�findallZages�names�test�print�rr�!/home/sivasurya/tutorial/regex.py�<module>s
```

I have two questions:

1. Why does the `__pycache__` folder created only for `file_regex.py` file
2. How can I delete `__pycache__` folder or a solution to this problem (I tried compiling the python file with `python -B file1.py` command, which didn't work)

P.S: I work in miniconda environment (python 3.x), if that helps

Comment: The `__pycache__` stores cached copies of bytecode. Only if you are explicitly *importing* the `file_regex.py` module is the cached bytecode for that module loaded. Nothing in `__pycache__` is ever automatically loaded without you explicitly having requested it.

Comment: But, the rest of the files is not importing the file_regex.py file..

Comment: The dependency can be transitive. Run Python with the `-v` switch to see all imports as they are executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually named the file as `regex.py`. when I deleted the `__pycache__` folder and changed the file name to `file_regex.py` the `__pycache__` folder didn't show up again and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

> This is because of the `__pycache__` folder . . .

This is incorrect.  The existence of the `__pycache__` folder has nothing to do with whether a file is run or not.  It simply holds the compiled files, nothing else.

If your `file_regex.py` keeps being executed it is because the other files have

```
import file_regex
```

or

```
from file_regex import ...
```

in them.

Comment: I'm only importing the following modules:

'import nltk
from nltk.corpus import state_union
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer'

Its nowhere importing the file_regex module.

Comment: What is happening that you think it is being imported?  Please update your question with the above comment, and the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my file was called "timeit.py" so a **pycache** folder was created every time I executed the file. The problem was that the file was the same name as the module so I solved the problem by changing the file name.